# Last-modified of a file - loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following webpage that pulls in the "last-modified" date of each file loaded:

http://f150.atwebpages.com/list.html

Now, do you see how it loads the dates 1 by 1 as it makes the calls to the header? If it didn't do it for you, hit F5 to reload the page.

Is there any way to call a global function, ajax/jquery call or something that sends all of the requests at once so it doesn't cause the page to load slowly?

(some of my pages have around 300 documents on them)

Thanks!

Comment: The page loaded instantly for me..

Comment: Hit F5...do you see the dates come in slower?  I eventually will be hosting this page in WebCenter, which in turn is sloooow.  Instead of hanging the page for 5-10 seconds, I'll have to see if anyone else has a slow load of the page.  Thanks!

Comment: You are already sending off all of the requests at once. The problem is that browsers are limited to the number of simultaneous http requests that can happen at once. The only real way to speed it up is to consolidate them all into a single request which will take a re-write of whatever script you are calling to get the modified value.

Answer (score 0):

No there are limits in how many requests you can do at once, and it doesn't make sense to have such an implementation that requires you to hammer the web server.

Instead make a handler on the backend using your favorite language where you can request a list of dates in one request

Comment: The only option I have for languages are html, javascript, jquery, ajax....no php, asp, cf etc.

Comment: @Lewis then there isn't anything you can do to speed it up short of adding a server-side language such as php asp cf node etc..

Comment: Might have some effect in some browsers if you have several domains to fetch from instead of just one, but other than that you have to get more control of the backend